# Bristol-Myers Squibb rights (BMY.RT) from sale of Celgene (CELG)

Tags: stocks

Can I sell my BMY.RT stock/rights before 12/31/21 if I choose to do so?  Do I have to exercise my rights or are they automatically exercised when a particular event occurs?

Answer (score 1):

BMY.RT is an exchange traded right and it can be sold at any time.